# Paradox about a-z vs A-Z

Tags: shell, case-sensitivity

I wrote a shell script to recognize the type of character

```
printf "Enter a character: "
read var
case "$var" in
[a-z])
        echo "You entered a lower case alphabet."
        ;;
[A-Z])
        echo "You entered an upper case alphabet."
        ;;
[0-9])
        echo "You entered a digit."
        ;;
?)
        echo "You entered a special simbol."
        ;;
*)
        echo "You entered more then one character."
        ;;
esac
```

But if input letter is whether lower-case or upper-case the output is:

> You entered a lower case alphabet.

The output is correct if I write it this way:

```
printf "Enter a character: "
read var
case "$var" in
[A-Z])
        echo "You entered a upper case alphabet."
        ;;
[a-z])
        echo "You entered an lower case alphabet."
        ;;
[0-9])
        echo "You entered a digit."
        ;;
?)
        echo "You entered a special simbol."
        ;;
*)
        echo "You entered more then one character."
        ;;
esac
```

Can't figure out why. The only logical answer is `[a-z]` includes lower-case and upper-case characters.

Comment: Try with `LANG=C` or `LC_COLLATE=C`.

Comment: Try with `[[:lower:]]`, `[[:upper:]]` instead. é is not a lower case character is the C locale.

Answer (score 1):

Lexical ordering depends on the locale. Differences are not restricted to "special" characters (e.g. `ä` like `a` in German, but after `z` in Finnish). Instead, in some locales, the ordering might be `AaBbCc…`, so `[a-z]` would expand to `[aBbCc…Zz]`. The patterns `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` mentioned by Stephane Chazelas are safe from these surprises.